# Can a well-ordered set isomorphic to a proper subset of itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Can a well-ordered set isomorphic to a proper subset of itself? Give an example or disprove it.

My answer: Yes We can. Consider $2\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Let $f$ be the function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $2\mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n)=2n$. We can see easily $f$ is isomorphism.

**Can you check my answer? Thanks...**

Comment: Yes I can "easily see" what you claim.  But is that enough for a rigorous proof?

Comment: @Gedgar Sorry, you are right. I should edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's fine, except that you should write “let $f$ be **the** function…”

More generally, $\mathbb N$ is order isomorphic with *every* infinite subset.

Comment: Thanks, okey, I edited.